# Iterate through Data tables and remove the columns in the List

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I have a `List<String>` that has allowed columns. and I have a dataset DT1 which has all the columns listed . Now that i want to do is to only get allowed columns from DT1.

```
List<String> = FirstName,LastName,Age,EmailAddress
DT1 contains = FirstName,LastName,Age,EmailAddress,Sex,PhoneNumber,Address
```

I have already tried `DataTable.Merge()` , `foreach` etc... but i couldn't get my expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your list is a `List<String>` containing the column names:

```
var toBeRemoved = DT1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                 .Where(c => !allowed.Contains(c.ColumnName))
                 .ToList();
foreach(DataColumn col in toBeRemoved)
{
     DT1.Columns.Remove(col);
}
```

**Edit**: You wanted to know how to set fields null which are in the removelist:

```
foreach(DataRow row in DT1.Rows) 
{
    foreach(DataColumn col in toBeRemoved)
    {
        row[col] = DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ThankYou for the quick help, Do tell me one thing more what if i dont remove the columns but set the value to NULL in that respective columns that were to be deleted.